# How many orthogonal basis does a set of vectors have?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, orthogonality

I wonder how many orthogonal bases does a set of vectors have in a space?

Comment: If you're asking how many different orthogonal sets of vectors can serve as a basis, then even in 3D space the answer is infinitely many.

Comment: What are your thoughts about that? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @ThongNguyenThanh  Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excluding the trivial case of set with just the zero vector, **orthogonal bases** are always infinitely many since we can scale the basis vectors as we want preserving orthogonality.

Otherwise for **orhonormal bases** we have

- $2$ choices for $1$ dimensional subspaces
- infinitely many choices for $n-$dimensional subspaces with $n\ge 2$

Comment: This assumes that the field is infinite?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes I'm referring to the ordinary vector spaces.

Comment: Whatever "ordinary" means. For people in coding theory, it would mean over finite fields.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I mean vector spaces over infinite fileds, the ones treated in the basic courses for linear algebra, people involved in "coding theory" is indeed not ordinary :)

Answer (score 1):

You have $n(n-1)/2$ degrees of freedom in choosing an orthogonal basis.

The first vector in the basis is a unit vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  It sits on the unit sphere, which is $n-1$-dimensional, and there are $n-1$ degrees of freedom to choose the first vector.

The rest of the basis vectors lie in a subspace orthogonal to the first, which is an $n-1$-dimensional space.  So, by induction, we have $n-2$ degrees of freedom to choose the second basis vector, and so on.  The total number of degrees of freedom is $$n-1 + (n-2) + (n-3) + ...+2+1+0 = n(n-1)/2$$

If we put the vectors of an orthogonal basis as columns in an $n\times n$ matrix, we get an 'orthogonal' matrix.  These matrices form the set $O(n)$, and all these matrices satisfy the equation $A^T A= I$, the identity matrix.

$O(n)$ is an $n(n-1)/2$-dimensional submanifold of the $n^2$-dimensional set of $n\times n$ matrices.

Comment: How do you know that we are in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: My fault, could you do the case of finite fields?